# How get a collection of models with no tags assigned - Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, tags, relationship, laravel-5.3

I am using [rtconner/laravel-tagging](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging) package to get tags functionality to my app.

I can count attached tags  by `$o->tags->count()`

I can loop the tags by a foreach: `@foreach($o->tags as $t)`.
print attached tags by

### the problem

Now I want to get a collection of random 10 Quotation with no tags attached.

While I can print a random 10 pieces with a given attribute:

```
$object = Quotation::where('deepness', null)->get()->random(10);
```

(Note: I have a random scope defined in the model, irrelevant for  my issue)

... but this code, cloned from another model doesn't work:

```
$object = Quotation::whereHas('tags','>',0)->get()->random(10);
```

It produces this error message:

`FatalThrowableError in Builder.php line 880:
Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, string given`

I have also tried to execute this query

```
$object = Quotation::has('tags')->get()->random(10);
```

but I got this:
```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2431:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tags()

```
Note 2: In the source model (the one I cloned from) the relation was counting a `hasMany` relation.

### to do

Please help me to create the collection of Quotations with no tags assigned

Comment: Can you try this $object = Quotation::where('tags', '>', 0)->get()->random(10);

Comment: That would be too easy. It produces `Unknown column 'tags'` error. Queries with `where` refer to the object. Queries with `has` or `whereHas` target related models, defined in the queried model file.

Comment: $object = Quotation::has('tags', '>=', 0)->get();

Comment: sane error: Type error: `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, string given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem and solved it this way:

```
$objects = Quotation::all();

$objects = $objects->filter(
                function ($object, $key) {
                    return $object->tags->count() > 0;
                }
            )->random(10);
```

Hope issues still relevant :)